# How to install boostrapGrowl to my Symfony application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I want to install the [BootstrapGrowl library](https://github.com/ifightcrime/bootstrap-growl/) to my Symfony2 application. I tried to do

```
composer require bootstrap-growl
composer install
```

And it has installed the library in the /vendor/ directory, however I have no idea on how to use it, because when I try to call it in my JS code, like

```
$.bootstrapGrowl("Message");
```

I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.bootstrapGrowl is not a function
```

I also tried including the file in my layout.html.twig file, but it's not possible - I get no hint from the IDE whatsoever. How should I do it properly so I could use the library in my project?

Comment: Have you included jquery.bootstrap-growl.min.js
bootstrap.min.css
bootstrap.min.js? Example  http://jsfiddle.net/ifightcrime/Us6WX/1008/

Answer (score 0):

Include the dependencies and **jquery.bootstrap-growl.min.js** into your page and call the following:

```
$.bootstrapGrowl("My message");
```

Don't forget to include jquery and bootstrap

**Available Options**

By default, growls use the standard 'alert' Bootstrap style, are 250px wide, right aligned, and are positioned 20px from the top right of the page.

```
$.bootstrapGrowl("another message, yay!", {
  ele: 'body', // which element to append to
  type: 'info', // (null, 'info', 'danger', 'success')
  offset: {from: 'top', amount: 20}, // 'top', or 'bottom'
  align: 'right', // ('left', 'right', or 'center')
  width: 250, // (integer, or 'auto')
  delay: 4000, // Time while the message will be displayed. It's not equivalent to the *demo* timeOut!
  allow_dismiss: true, // If true then will display a cross to close the popup.
  stackup_spacing: 10 // spacing between consecutively stacked growls.
});
```

Comment: I've already done this in the first place. When I include this file and try to call it, no scripts load and everything breaks down.